# In Visual Studio 2010, for SharePoint development, why does the package & feature designers list all items from all projects in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Instead of just listing the items in the current project?

As a Visual Studio project maps (?) to a single WSP, I'd expect to see the items in the current project listed instead of all the items from the entire solution. It's not a problem for small projects, but if you're working with a project that has >1 project, each containing multiple items, it's a big ol' mess.

Or, why isn't there even an option to view all items in the solution OR all items in the current project?

Answer (score 0):

Package and feature designer is new to VS2010 and hope this will be improved in a future release as according to your suggestions.

If you wanted to see the items related to a project then temporarily exclude other projects in the solution explorer.